# How to implement custom authentication on OData

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, odata

I want to guard OData service with custom authentication associated to a user table in database. I have been obssessed with this problem and searched solutions for a long time in vain. I mean, yes, there are quite a lot articles on the web but they are just quite trivial, for example implementing IPrincipal or IHttpContext with basic authentication on. Notably, many of them can data back to 2010 where OData is not as mature as today. So I'm wondering if there is any rapid solution to database-based custom authentication.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not clear what to me what you mean by with custom authentication associated to a user table in database.

Comment: @Blam I mean actually I already have a database in which user credentials are stored. Consequently, the default ASP.NET authentication won't fit in the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData and authentication (and even authorization for that matter) are unrelated for the most part by design. That doesn't mean that OData stacks can't provide good support for authentication and authorization, just that the OData protocol itself doesn't comment on it. Protocol aside, both Web API and WCF Data Services are working on getting better support here. Speaking as a member of the .NET community (and not as a Microsoft employee), I think it's reasonable to expect that as those stacks implement authorization APIs they will probably be looking to claims-based authorization. Again, I want to state explicitly that I'm not trying to hide or divulge any plans here - I'm merely speculating about where authentication and authorization are going.

In a nutshell, if I were in your shoes I'd find the easiest intersection I could between OAuth2 and claims-based authentication and make that work for now. Working out your claims and authentication now means that you only would need to consider integrating the actual authorization code later.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Yes, OAuth is gaining popularity these days and is definitely a fitting solution. However, in my case, it's not that viable because I have to base the authentication on an internal database which is already there. Anyway, I'm figuring whether it's appropriate for me to use basic authentication with a custom header attached to every single request.

Comment: Appropriate isn't something I can comment on since I don't know your scenario all that well. OAuth is still a completely viable candidate - you would just have an OAuth server that deals with those credentials. An alternative would be Forms authentication. I think the fundamental point I was trying to make is that OData itself doesn't really care what you use to authenticate.

Comment: Also, note that using a custom header (or anything other than one of the "standard" auth mechanisms) would create ecosystem issues. For example, you might not be able to get your data into Excel. If you use Forms auth or Windows auth or OAuth, I believe you should be able to make most of the OData ecosystem work.

Comment: Truly that's a point to consider. And things turn out to be more complicated in my scenario where the existing authentication and presentation system is built on Java, Hibernate and Oracle, while now I need to code Silverlight for a more responsive and interactive client side. Maybe it's better for me to build the service in Java than choose the .NET solution, though the latter works seamlessly with Silverlight and other similar frontend technologies I think. Anyway, custom authentication really isn't a good way in essence.